# How to get button x,y coordinate in a textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, coordinates, uiscreen

I have 4 different buttons for every corner of the screen. Just need to show their coordinates for every device changes in a text field or a label.

“x0” - button x coordinate on the screen
“y0” - button y coordinate on the screen

i should show like x = "x0" ; y = "y0"

Comment: swift? objective c? are you using auto layout?

Comment: objective c. And yes i am using auto layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy built-in way to log frames. Use `NSStringFromCGRect(frame);` to show the coordinates of the button.

Comment: Can i set this adding additional info like adding X:    self.lblForInfo.text = @"X:"(NSStringFromCGRect(_firstButton.frame)); @FabioBerger

Comment: Is that a question? You can set the text with a formatted string like this: ```self.lblForInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(_firstButton.frame)];```

Comment: okay what about when i want to show more than one info in a same textfield ... ? self.lblForInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X2:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(_secondButton.frame), @"X1:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(_firstButton.frame)]; @FabioBerger

Comment: almost, it would be like this ```self.lblForInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X2:%@ X1:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(_secondButton.frame),NSStringFromCGRect(_firstButton.frame)];```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can directly print a `CGRect` using `NSStringFromCGRect`, here is a sample of what you are looking for. I'm just putting button1's coordinates in text field.

```
UIButton *button1, *button2, *button3, *button4;

CGFloat button1X = button1.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat button1Y = button1.frame.origin.y;

CGFloat button2X = button2.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat button2Y = button2.frame.origin.y;

CGFloat button3X = button3.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat button3Y = button3.frame.origin.y;

CGFloat button4X = button4.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat button4Y = button4.frame.origin.y;

NSString *button1Coords = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x = \"%f\" x = \"%f\"", button1X, button1Y];

self.textField.text = button1Coords;
```